# Adcolony not working(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ads, adcolony

I am trying to add Adcolony in my app. This is my code:

```
[AdColony configureWithAppID:myAppID
                         zoneIDs:@[myZoneID]
                        delegate:self
                         logging:YES];
[AdColony playVideoAdForZone:myZoneID withDelegate:self withV4VCPrePopup:YES andV4VCPostPopup:YES];

-(void)onAdColonyV4VCReward:(BOOL)success currencyName:(NSString *)currencyName currencyAmount:(int)amount inZone:(NSString *)zoneID
{  
    if (success) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

But the ads are never appearing.

Here are the logs:

```
ADCOLONY 2.2.4 [info] AdColony library version: 2.2.4 32-bit production
[info] Developer logging enabled
[trace] Configuration succeeded!
[info] Ads are not ready for zone (myZoneID) with slot 0
ADCOLONY 2.2.4 [info] Ads are ready for zone (myZoneID) with slot 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your configuration has succeeded, this may be because your app is not live in the App Store yet.  Our system does not send live ads to apps that are not able to be downloaded by players.

To turn on test ads, log into the AdColony dashboard (https://clients.adcolony.com) and open the app you are working with.  Go into the settings for each of the zones you are using and select Yes for "Show test ads only?"; then click the Save button below this.

If you are already using test ads, please reach out to our Support Team at support@adcolony.com for further assistance.

Comment: Ok thanks it works now but the `onAdColonyV4VCReward:` method never gets called

Comment: @AbdullahShafique, the solution for us was to set to app to "client side" on the dashboard.